# Can I make string literal into identifier

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In Visual C++, given this function declaration:

```
int main();
```

In function body, I want to define a varible which has a type same as function's (return) type, but suppose I don't want to use either int or main, so I tried something like this:

```
int main() {
    decltype(__identifier(__FUNCTION__)) x;
}
```

This doesn't work because __identifier doesn't accept string literal. Can I use some method to make string literal into identifier? Or, is there a way we can define x of type int within function body, without use of return type (int) or function name (main)?

Comment: Making the string literal into an identifier will not solve this because of overloading et al. I suggest rewording your question to emphasize wanting to deduce the return type of the function you're in. Better yet, explain why you would want to do this? In what scenario do you not know the function's return type?

Comment: Templates may be what you are looking for, but for the best possible answer explain why you want to do this, then someone can explain the best way to solve your real problem in C++.

Comment: This makes no sense. How could you not know what return type the function you're currently in has? Is it for "forwards compatability" and being "future proof"? YAGNI. Chances are, if the return type changes, the value that is returned will change aswell so this will be useless.

Comment: @tenfour I do this merely for fun :D you are right that we need signature here, decltype(__identifier(__FUNCTION__)) x should really be decltype(__identifier(__FUNCTION__)()) x. I always think that we should get more compile time information.

Comment: @Xeo this works. int main() { decltype(main()) x; }

Comment: But didn't you say you didn't want to mention `int` or `main`?

Comment: @Xeo yes I don't want int or main, so I don't use them. But we can know what return type the function we're currently in has.

Comment: I never said it was impossible, I only sad that it "makes no sense", "YAGNI" and that it "will be useless".

Comment: @Xeo "How could you not know what return type the function you're currently in has?" Aha, there is a "not" which I didn't notice before :D

Comment: Well, I was not referring to `decltype`. You're currently writing this function, how can you not know what it should return?

Comment: @Xeo Some type doesn't have a name, 1. unnamed type, struct { int n; } f() { return ?? }, 2. inplace object, such as a recursive lambda function, what's its name?

Comment: `struct { int n; } f() { return ?? }` is ill-formed, and a lambda type can only be returned with `std::function` or similar constructs.

Comment: @Xeo void (*f())() { return [] { }; }

Comment: Like I said, a *lambda type*. What you have is the implicit conversion of a non-capturing lambda to a function pointer.

Comment: @Xeo The returned lambda is a joke. Why struct { int n; } f() { return ?? } is ill-formed?

Comment: Oh, I see. And for the function, because the standard says so. :) [`error: new types may not be defined in a return type`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/0d770475bceca2f22123fc4fa1348ca4)

Comment: @Xeo I remember Bjarne Stroustrup said we can define a type as function's return type. When I looked at page 817 of <The C++ Programming Language 3> special ed., it says `struct S { int x, y; } f(); /* C. Not C++ */`. So I was wrong. `struct { int n; } f() { return ?? }` is indeed not valid C++.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it does accept string literals, but you have to suppress a warning for it to work. You can do this:

```
#define SYMBOL_FROM_STRING(S) (__pragma(warning(suppress: 4483)) __identifier(S))

decltype(SYMBOL_FROM_STRING(__FUNCTION__)) x;
```